# pyinstaller opening window of my game but not creating exe

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

So once I go through `pyinstaller platform.py --onefile -w`
A popup window of my game comes up and I can play it fine. But going into dist folder, there is no exe file. And once I close the game, these tracebacks come in.

Please help. Thank you.

```
E:\Sublime Text 3\Projects>pyinstaller platform.py --onefile -w
51 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.2
51 INFO: Python: 3.10.5
58 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.22000-SP0
59 INFO: wrote E:\Sublime Text 3\Projects\platform.spec
60 INFO: UPX is not available.
61 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['E:\\Sublime Text 3\\Projects']
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.10.5)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html

And then after I quit my game this comes in

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Manny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Manny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Manny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Manny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 178, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\Manny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 59, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Manny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 842, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "C:\Users\Manny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 764, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "E:\Sublime Text 3\Projects\platform.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(
  File "C:\Users\Manny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 287, in __init__
    self.hookspath += discover_hook_directories()
  File "C:\Users\Manny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\isolated\_parent.py", line 269, in wrapped
    return call(function, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Manny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\isolated\_parent.py", line 238, in call
    return isolated.call(function, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Manny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\isolated\_parent.py", line 176, in call
    raise RuntimeError(f"Child process call to {function.__name__}() failed with:\n" + output)
RuntimeError: Child process call to discover_hook_directories() failed with:
  File "C:\Users\Manny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\isolated\_child.py", line 63, in run_next_command
    output = function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Manny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 105, in discover_hook_directories
    from PyInstaller.log import logger
  File "C:\Users\Manny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from PyInstaller import compat
  File "C:\Users\Manny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 42, in <module>
    is_win_10 = is_win and (platform.win32_ver()[0] == '10')
AttributeError: module 'platform' has no attribute 'win32_ver'[enter image description here][1]
```

[[image: 1]]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the Problem is but try this

```
pyinstaller --onefile platform.py
```

or Try reinstalling `pyinstaller`

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled. Tried your way and the same thing is happening. I'll keep researching. Thank you.